# Strange behaviour on Firebase query result SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm getting this error on the line `let itemToAdd = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Shop`a function that retrieves data from Firebase.
the output of the console in `Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1118c8de0) to 'NSString' (0x10dda45d8).`.
What I'm trying to do is to filter database ordering by one value 
`opening Time`and than get another value `Shop Name`from the returned entries in the snapshot.

here's the function:

```
func filterOpenShops(enterDoStuff: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Shops").child("Shops Opening Times")
let query = ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "Opening Time").queryStarting(atValue: openingTimeQueryStart).queryEnding(atValue: openingTimeQueryEnd)
query?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        // new modification
        if childSnapshot is DataSnapshot {
            let itemToAdd = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Shop Name").value as! String // gets the open shop from snapshot
        self.availableShopsArray.append(itemToAdd)
        print(snapshot.children)
         print(" Open Shops are \(self.availableShopsArray)")


        }
    }
    // still asynchronous part
    enterDoStuff(true)
    // call next cascade function filterClosedShops only when data
})

// Sychronous part

print("opening query start is \(openingTimeQueryStart) and opening query end is \(openingTimeQueryEnd)")


} // end of filterOpenShops()
```

EDIT:

```
I rewrote the function as:


    func filterOpenShops(enterDoStuff: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        // get from Firebase snapshot all shops opening times into an array of tuples
        //shopOpeningTimeArray:[(storeName: String, weekdayNumber: String, opening1: Sring, closing1: String, opening2:String, closing2: String)]

        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Shops").child("Shops Opening Times")
        let query = ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "Opening Time").queryStarting(atValue: String(describing: openingTimeQueryStart)).queryEnding(atValue: String(describing :openingTimeQueryEnd))
        query?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in // original is ok
//            guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }



            for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {

                print("snapshot is: \(childSnapshot)")
                print("snapshot.childrend is: \(snapshot.children)")
                guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }

                let itemToAdd = data["Shop Name"]
                self.availableShopsArray.append(itemToAdd!)
                print("Open Shop is: \(String(describing: itemToAdd))")
                print(" Open Shops are \(self.availableShopsArray)")



            }
            // still asynchronous part
            enterDoStuff(true)
            // call next cascade function filterClosedShops only when data
            print(" Open Shops are \(self.availableShopsArray)")
        })

        print("opening query start is \(openingTimeQueryStart) and opening query end is \(openingTimeQueryEnd)")


    } // end of filterOpenShops()
```

but I still get a null object and not a [String:String] as expected.

The function that created the entries in Firebase is:

```
    func postOpeningTime() {

//        if shopNameTextfield.text != nil && openingTimeTextfield.text != nil && closingTimeTextfield.text != nil {
            let shopName = shopNameTextfield.text!
            let openingTime = openingTimeTextfield.text!
            let closingTime = closingTimeTextfield.text!
//        } else {return}

        let post: [String:String] = [
            "Shop Name" : shopName ,
            "Opening Time" : openingTime ,
            "Closing Time" : closingTime
            ]
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref?.child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Shops").child("Shops Opening Times").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

    }
```

Now I have two behaviours:

1st: When querying for entries and finds values that are Int: completion get called but I get no snapshot print.
2nd: When querying for entries and find values that are String: completion doesn't get called but snapshot prints the right entries with values.

Can anyone please spot what's going on here?

Comment: Your shop name is null somewhere. So instead of using 'as!' try using 'if let'

Comment: I'm using values for the search that should give me results. how do I check what's in the snapshot I get?

Comment: Try logging snapshot.children before running for loop. You might get to see values

Comment: I printend childSnapshot and it has a result: `childSnapshot is: Snap (Arma Wed Mor) {
    "Closing Time" = 41230;
    "Opening Time" = 40830;
    "Shop Name" = Armaroli;
}´ so the query is finding the right data. I just want to get the shop name from it

Comment: @sanman. Interestingly enough I repeated the search to a value that should return 2 shops but still I only get the same as before.  can it be because I'm printing `childSnapshot`from inside the for in loop? I'll try and print `snapshot.children` instead before the loop

Comment: ok.. the output from those prints is: `snapsot is: Snap (Shops Opening Times) {
    "Arma Wed Mor" =     {
        "Closing Time" = 41230;
        "Opening Time" = 40830;
        "Shop Name" = Armaroli;
    };
    "Spezial Wed" =     {
        "Closing Time" = 41900;
        "Opening Time" = 41000;
        "Shop Name" = "Spezial Cycle";
    };
}
snapshot.childrend is: <FTransformedEnumerator: 0x6000029dee40>
childSnapshot is: Snap (Arma Wed Mor) {
    "Closing Time" = 41230;
    "Opening Time" = 40830;
    "Shop Name" = Armaroli;
}`,why in` snapshot.chidren`
 I only get 1 shop?

Comment: I'm having a doubt. Can it be that the problem is that I created the database manually, therefore I didn't specify that values where strings? If so, how to specify it? When i'l create entries in the nodes I will specify values to be String dough

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Can you please check the question under EDITS and see if you see the problem? Thanks

Comment: @sanman. Can you please check the question under EDITS and see if you see the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to bee the way I was casting query result.
Casting it as [String:String] produced to return because upshot was actually [String[String:String]] when all the values for entry's parameter were String, but as I changed Opening Time and Closing time to be Int, than I have to read the snapshot as [String[String:Any]].
So the final function is:

```
func filterOpenShops(setCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        // Empty the array for beginning of the search
        self.availableShopsArray.removeAll()
        var ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Shops").child("Shops Opening Times").queryOrdered(byChild: "Opening Time").queryStarting(atValue: openingTimeQueryStart).queryEnding(atValue: openingTimeQueryEnd).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String : [String : Any]] {
                for (_, value) in
                    data {
                        let shopName = value["Shop Name"] as! String
                        let active = value["Active"] as! String
                        if active == "true" {
                            self.availableShopsArray.append(shopName)
                            print("Shop_Name is :\(shopName)")
                            print("self.availableShopsArray is: \(self.availableShopsArray)")
                        }
                }

            } else {
                print("No Shops")
            }
            // still asynchronous part
            setCompletion(true)
            // call next cascade function filterClosedShops only when data retrieving is finished
            self.filterClosedShops(setCompletion: self.completionSetter)

            print("  1 Open Shops are \(self.availableShopsArray)")
        }
    } // end of filterOpenShops()
```